# How to not return anything in a COND

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

So I'm making this function in lisp, and in the `cond` part basically if a condition is met, I return a list with 2 values, and if the condition is not met, I would like to not return anything at all! Here it is:

```
(defun lista-dos-aprovados (turma)
  (mapcar (lambda (aluno)
            (cond ((> (media-notas (notas aluno)) 9.5)
                   (list (first aluno) (second aluno)))
                  (t nil)))
          turma))
```

the names are in portuguese but I think it doesn't really matter here. What I'd like to do is when the code reaches the `(t nil)` part, I don't want it to write `NIL` inside my list. I tried not having the `T` condition or leaving it empty after the `T`, still it always writes `NIL`.

Comment: Any particular reason why you are not able to post code which is formatted for human readability?

Comment: @RainerJoswig, this is a recurring theme, so perhaps pointing to an article that describes how to do so would be more constructive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the `nil` in the result of `mapcar`, like in:

```
(defun lista-dos-aprovados (turma)
  (remove nil
          (mapcar (lambda (aluno)
                    (cond ((> (media-notas (notas aluno)) 9.5)
                           (list (first aluno) (second aluno)))
                          (t nil)))
                  turma)))
```

and note that you can simplify the function as:

```
(defun lista-dos-aprovados (turma)
  (remove nil
          (mapcar (lambda (aluno)
                    (when (> (media-notas (notas aluno)) 9.5)
                      (list (first aluno) (second aluno))))
                  turma)))
```

or you can use a `loop`:

```
(defun lista-dos-aprovados (turma)
  (loop for aluno in turma 
     when (> (media-notas (notas aluno)) 9.5)
     collect (list (first aluno) (second aluno))))
```

Comment: Another option would be to use **mapcan** and have the lambda function always return a list.  It already does in the `(t nil)` case, and it would just require the other clause to return `(list (list (first ...) (second ...)))`.

Comment: thank you ! so simple after all! i didnt know how to use the When statement